# SMPP registered_delivery

Tags: smpp

I would like to know where to add this parameter in the 
SMPP bind, so its default value will be changes from 0 to 1.

To be more clear I would like that this parameter to be set to 1 in 
the submit_sm.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, From where is this registered_delivery flag to be set to 1?

Answer (score 6):

SMPP 3.4 spec, section 5.2.17 can answer most of your question.

"registered_delivery" field is used to request for delivery confirmation(s). This field can only be set at PDU level, not a bind level.

There are different types of delivery confirmation. You can request for none, one, some or all of them. registered_delivery is represented by 1 byte and is set to 0x00 by default; this means all types of delivery confirmation is disabled. You need to set different bits to override.

Here is a list of possible configurations:

#### For SMSC Delivery Receipt (bits 1 and 0)

- x x x x x x 0 0 => No SMSC Delivery Receipt requested (default).
- x x x x x x 0 1 => SMSC Delivery Receipt requested where final delivery outcome is delivery success or failure.
- x x x x x x 1 0 => SMSC Delivery Receipt requested where the final delivery outcome is delivery failure.
- x x x x x x 1 1 => Reserved.

#### For SME originated Acknowledgement (bits 3 and 2)

- x x x x 0 0 x x => No recipient SME acknowledgment requested (default).
- x x x x 0 1 x x => SME Delivery Acknowledgement requested.
- x x x x 1 0 x x => SME Manual/User Acknowledgment requested.
- x x x x 1 1 x x => Both Delivery and Manual/User Acknowledgment requested.

#### For Intermediate Notification (bit 5)

- x x x 0 x x x x => No Intermediate notification requested (default).
- x x x 1 x x x x => Intermediate notification requested.

As you can see, it's possible request for 3 different types of delivery confirmations.

Sending request for one or more types of delivery confirmation does not guarantee that it will be obliged by the SMSC. It is up to the SMSC how exactly it will implement it.

Comment: Beware that the text "For Intermediate Notification (bit 5)" is inconsistent with the bit pattern in the SMPP 3.4 spec, while they are consistent in the SMPP 5 spec (bit 4, same bit pattern).